# Bound on difference of roots between two “close” polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $p(z) = z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots+a_0$ and $q(z) = z^n + b_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots+b_0$ be two complex monic polynomials with $|a_i - b_i| < \epsilon < 1$. Furthermore, assume that all the coefficients of both polynomials are bounded in modulus by some fixed number $K$. Then I believe that the Hausdorff distance between the roots of $p$ and $q$ considered as sets in the complex plane is atmost $C(K,n)\times \epsilon^{1/n}$ where $C(K,n)$ is a constant that depends on $K$ and $n$. Is this true?

Comment: You might look at [Wilkinson's polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial) where a tiny change in one coefficient makes a large change in the roots.  It is not quite a counterexample because the coefficients are large, but it is enlightening.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks! This is interesting. From what I understand, it is still possible that my claim above is still correct in spite of this example?

Comment: Yes, if $a$ is an $m$-fold root of $p$, $p(z)=(z-a)^mp_1(z)$, then a perturbation $p+ϵr$ has in first order roots close to $a$ at $0=(z-a)^mp_1(a)+ϵr(a)$, $z=a+q_m^k\sqrt[m]{ϵr(a)/p_1(a)}$ with $q_m$ the $m$-th unit root and  $p_1(a)=p^{(m)}(a)/m!$. The number $C(K,n)$ has then to be a bound $|m!r(a)/p^{(m)}(a)|^{1/m}$ for all possible $m$, plus a little more to account for the higher order terms.